# Bash Script to Print Full Path Names Based on Size

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to write a script that prints out the full path names of my files over a specified size and the size needs to be read as a argument. I am not familiar with bash at all so I haven't tried much.

Answer (score 3):

Searching files with specific size and print their location can be done with the following:

```
find / -type f -size 1M
```

This will search `/` for files sized 1 MB and print their full location...

To use that as a script you can use something similar to this

```
#!/bin/sh
find / -type f -size $*
```

Where the parameter would be the size of the file like `100M`

Other example that display the size of the file with `du` or `ls`

```
find / -type f -size 1M -exec du {} \;
# or
find / -type f -size 1M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Alternative with sort and du

```
find / -type f -size 5M -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -h
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried your command line and it told me "find: missing argument to '-exec' ". After some searching I found this but I am not sure how to specify a size: du -sh -- * | sort -h

Comment: @rikito104 in that case you didn't type the command exactly as shown in this answer. Please try again - the punctuation is important (the `{}` and the `\;` in particular)

Comment: Also, (I think) one rarely finds files of an exact 1M size, you may want `-size +1M` for files greater than 1M, or `-files -1M` for files less than, etc.